# How does CALL instruction parsed into hex?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have written a simple C code is like:

```
int add2(int a) {
  return a+2;
}

int main()
{
  int a=0;
  a = add2(a);
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

and when I use objdump I found this:

```
  400558:       e8 d8 ff ff ff          callq  400535 <add2>
```

I'm wondering the relationship between the hex code `e8 d8 ff ff ff` and `callq 400535 <add2>`. I searched and found the hex code of callq is `e8`, but what about `d8 ff ff ff`? does it has some relationship with the address that callq calls? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are *many* resources about x86 assembly all over the Internet. Look up the  `callq` instruction and what it operands might mean.

Comment: `0x400558 + sizeof(callq instruction) + 0xffffffd8` equals `0x400535` when truncated to 32 bits.

Comment: As a hint, I recommend you learn about [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) representation of negative numbers, as well as [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (especially [little endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at [this instruction reference](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html), you will see that the opcode `E8` for `call` has two possible operands, `rel16` and `rel32`, which mean a relative address displacement of either 16 or 32-bits from the next instruction pointer. The `d8 ff ff ff` is, when interpreted as a 32-bit two's complement value stored in little-endian, the relative displacement `0xFFFFFFD8`, which is `-40`, so the `call` instruction is calling the code that begins `-40` bytes before the end of the `call` instruction itself as a function.